MAUI .NET 8 iOS - Span TapGestureRecognizer not working
I have created a new MAUI .NET 8 project and migrated the Xamarin forms project code.
In iOS, the span text TapGestureRecognizer is not working.
gesture_Tapped event is not triggered.
var sp2 = new Span { Text = "Click here" };
TapGestureRecognizer gesture = new TapGestureRecognizer
{
    NumberOfTapsRequired = 1
};

sp2.GestureRecognizers.Add(gesture);



gesture.Tapped += gesture_Tapped;


private void gesture_Tapped(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmailTest email = new EmailTest();
    email.SendEmail(StringConstants.TEXT_EMAIL);
}

How do I resolve this issue?

I am not sure how working is this now, but like a year ago, I was fighting with this issue. I was unable to figure out how to get it working. So all my tapped commands were moved to Label level, styled with bluish text color and underlined text decoration.

This is a bug with .NET MAUI https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4734
And it was fixed in Microsoft.Maui.Control version v8.0.40
Make sure you use that version and I am sure it will work
If you can't update then you can also use this workaround https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4734#issuecomment-1929107569

I'm using .NET 8 and I'm targeting Android API Level 34. The version of Microsoft.Maui.Control I use in the project is 8.0.70.
I have 3 Span.GestureRecognizers in my code, 1 for a Command, 1 for an ICommand and 1 for a RelayCommand. None of the 3 commands work, so I guess the problem is the TapGestureRecognizer.
The issue doesn't seem fixed to me!

I tested all Microsoft.Maui.Controls versions starting from 8.0.40: 8.0.40, 8.0.60, 8.0.61 and 8.0.70. None of them seems to work for me...

I recommend you use the other link in that case and create that handler

Is a handler needed for Android too? The post only suggests one for iOS.

Are you facing the issue in Android as well? Ideally you should not

I'm only targeting Android, so my problem is with Android. What's the solution for Android? Is it only to add <Label.GestureRecognizers> <TapGestureRecognizer/> </Label.GestureRecognizers> in the XAML code in the respective Label, without using an Android specific handler? If the answer is yes, then the solution does not work in my case. Adding a TapGestureRecognizer for the Span's Label has no effect.
